# How to combine Tabview with Dynamic Graphic to change the colour of a polygon

Tags: graphics, dynamic, gui-construction, code-review

1. How does one get `TabView` to specify the `colour` of the `Polygon`?
2. How does one put a label on the slider: `label => "number of sides = {}"`.

   ```
   DynamicModule[{p, colour},
    {
     Dynamic[Graphics[{colour, Polygon[CirclePoints[p]]}]],

     Slider[Dynamic[p], {3, 17, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],

     Dynamic[TabView[{colour -> Green, colour -> Orange}]]

   }]
   ```

Note: Detailed Explanations welcome. Im a determined beginner. Does it have something to do with the way `TabView` interacts with Set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TabView` is for viewing. You can associate color changes with the second argument of `TabView` but it will be easier to just use what is designed for that, like `SetterBar`.

Moreover, the less inside `Dynamic` the better so instead of creating whole `Graphics` you can just tell the FrontEnd to take care of that `colour` and `Polygon`.

```
DynamicModule[{p = 3, colour = Green}
 ,
 Column @ {
   Graphics[{
     Dynamic@colour,
     Dynamic@Polygon[CirclePoints[p]]
     }, PlotRange -> 1
   ],
   Row[{
     Slider[Dynamic[p], {3, 17, 1}],
     "number of sides = {", Dynamic@p, "}"
     }, Spacer[5]
   ],
   SetterBar[Dynamic@colour, {Red, Green, Orange}]
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the natural and idiomatic way to do it:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{colour, Polygon[CirclePoints[sides]]}], 
           {sides, 3, 17, 1},
           {{colour, Orange}, {Green -> "Green", Orange -> "Orange"}} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The guy is trying to use `DynamicModule`, don't put him off the right path! :)

Comment: @Kuba Are you the same `Kuba` who posted that entangled solution above? :D

Comment: Yep :) I think `Manipulate` is ok if you are not going to care about details and your apps are going to be relatively small. Otherwise habits from extensive use of `Manipulate` will drive you crazy :) And you know that! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is more or less directly cribbed from the help:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{color, Polygon[CirclePoints[sides]]}],
{{sides, 3,"Number of Sides"}, 3, 17, 1}, {color, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]